# Add css as <link tag that @import another css from node_modules

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, next.js, server-side-rendering

How ca I import this css.. `/styles/app.css` that contains only one import...

```
@import 'normalize.css';
```

Into my `_document` as `<link` tag

```
import stylesheet from 'styles/app.css'

....

<link rel="stylesheet" href={stylesheet) />
```

The `next.config.js` config...

```
config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'emit-file-loader',
    options: {name: 'dist/[path][name].[ext]'}
});
config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [                        {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
            context: 'public',
            name: 'styles/[name]-[hash].[ext]',
            publicPath: '/',
        },
    }, 'postcss-loader']
});
```

But the structure generated in dist folder is wrong

[image]

and I get 404 on console..

[image]

**Check [online here](https://ssr-starter.now.sh/)**

Comment: Next.js exposes files only from /static directory. If you have custom route, you need to setup routes on higher level. For example ExpressJS or Nginx.

Comment: And if I put the `app.css` file inside the `/static` folder?

And in my `_document.js` I import like.. `import stylesheet from 'static/styles/app.css'`

Comment: I tried and I get the same error.. check 
https://zeit.co/ridermansb/ssr-starter/oblikqkrvz

Comment: did you figure this out @ridermansb